# When open panel group, check radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to apply some other tutorials found here in stackoverflow to achieve this, but no success, I dont know what I'm doing wrong...

So the code above is my current collapsible group panel, what I want to achieve is:
When I click in one of them, I want the radiobutton to be checked, any tips?

```
        <div class="panel-group" id="panel-payment-options">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-payment-options" href="#panel-credit-card">
                        <label for="credit-card">
                            <input type="radio" value="credit-card" id="credit-card" name="paymentmethod"> Cartão de Crédito
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="panel-credit-card" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Content for credit card
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-payment-options" href="#panel-internet-banking">
                        <label for="internet-banking">
                            <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="internet-banking" value="internet-banking"> Internet Banking
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="panel-internet-banking" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Content for internet banking
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-payment-options" href="#panel-boleto">
                        <label for="boleto">
                            <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="boleto" value="boleto"> Boleto
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="panel-boleto" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        content for boleto
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this JQuery 3 lines :

```
$(".panel-title").click(function() {
    $(this).children().children().prop("checked", true);
});
```

[**Try Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mv8znhf6/)

Comment: Thank you so much, last question now, how can i make the panels to show closed every time the page loads?

Comment: Just remove the class `in`, in your first panel to close all panels by default. Becomes: `class="panel-collapse collapse"`